# getting notice undefined index

Tags: php, notice

I have read the following [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index) however I haven't figured out the problem in my case.

I am getting the notice:undefined index below, when as far as I know I have defined infoID:

> Notice: Undefined index: infoID in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevelopment\Bathrooms\functions.php on line 193

```
function info_byidx($sql) {
            include 'connect.php';
    $id = $_GET['infoID'];
    $select = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $select->bind_param('s', $id);
    $select->execute();
    $select->store_result();
    if ($select->num_rows > 0) {
        $meta = $select->result_metadata();
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
            $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
        }
        call_user_func_array(array($select, 'bind_result'), $params);
        while ($select->fetch()) {
            if ($row['title'] == "NULL") {
                echo "<h3>".$row['subtitle']."</h3>\n<p>".$row['content']."</p>\n";
            }
            else if ($row['subtitle'] == "NULL") {
                echo "<h2>".$row['title']."</h2>\n<p>".$row['content']."</p>\n";
            }
            else {
            echo "<h2>".$row['title']."</h2>\n<h3>".$row['subtitle']."</h3>\n<p>".$row['content']."</p>\n";
            }

        }
        $select->close();
    }

}
```

infoID is defined thru:

> `http://localhost:1234/WebDevelopment/Bathrooms/info.php?pageID=2?infoID=x` -- where is the value of generalID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://localhost:1234/WebDevelopment/Bathrooms/info.php?pageID=2?infoID=x
```

fix it to

```
http://localhost:1234/WebDevelopment/Bathrooms/info.php?pageID=2&infoID=x
```

just one ? at first, then use & to seperate next key=values.